# Django: routing same model but different category field to separate URLs

Tags: django, routes, django-urls

I have the following model and url routes.  There is one Post model that I want to route to different URLs based on the category.  Is there a way to do this by passing in extra information in `app/urls.py`?

In `app/posts/models.py`

```
class Post(models.Model):
    author = ...
    title = ...
    body = ...
    category = models.CharField()
```

In `app/urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    (r'^blog/', include('posts.urls'), {'category': 'blog'}),
    (r'^school/', include('posts.urls'), {'category': 'school'}),
)
```

My understanding is that the extra info from `app/urls.py` is included in each url route in `app/posts/urls.py`.  Is there a way to use that information?  What can I put in place of the exclamation points below?

In `app/posts/urls.py`

```
from models import Post

queryset = Post.objects.order_by('-pub_date')

urlpatterns = patterns(
    'django.views.generic.list_detail',
    url(r'^$', 'object_list',
        {'queryset': queryset.filter(category=!!!!!!)}
        name="postRoot"),

    url(r'^(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', 'object_detail',
        {'queryset': queryset.filter(category=!!!!!!)},
        name="postDetail")
    )
```

Thanks, joe

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not aware of a way to use the URL parameters the way you have indicated. If anyone knows better, do correct me.

I faced a similar situation some time ago and made do with a thin wrapper over the `list_detail` view.

```
# views.py
from django.views.generic.list_detail import object_list

def object_list_wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
    category = kwargs.pop('category')
    queryset = Post.objects.filter(category = category)
    kwargs['queryset'] = queryset
    return object_list(*args, **kwargs)

#urls.py
urlpatterns = patterns('myapp.views',
    url(r'^$', 'object_list_wrapper', {}, name="postRoot"),        
...
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is the answer. In my experience parameters captured by urlpatterns can only be retrieved from a view function.

Comment: Yea, I think so too but figured I'd ask.  Anyway it worked so many thanks to you.

Comment: @JordanReiter parameters can be retrieved from a view class by using `self.kwargs`.

Comment: @Bobort this answer is from 2010. Django has changed considerably since then. Even then, my answer is still correct — whether using a class-based view or a function-based view, that's still where you would access the kwargs; they would not be available to urlpatterns.

Comment: @JordanReiter, I interpreted your comment that you can't access parameters from a class-based view. Your words: "only be retrieved from a view function." I added my clarification to those visitors from 2021 who might get the wrong idea that you can't access kwargs from a class-based view.